# Can't connect to dedicated video card using vga_switcheroo

Tags: kernel, graphics, amd-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

So I have an Intel 5500 as integrated GPU and AMD R5 M430 as Dedicated (Discrete) GPU, I installed Oibaf's Drivers and vga_switcheroo and I want to switch to the Dedicated GPU, forever.

Here's the output for `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:0d:00.0`

And when I do `sudo echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` which is connecting to the Dedicated GPU, I get this error `bash: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Permission denied`

How can I connect to the Dedicated (AMD) GPU, and do I need to connect everytime I reboot my laptop?

Comment: @ElderGeek it doesn't work, when I switch off lightdm, the computer freeze and I have no backlight.

Comment: Perhaps if you would be so kind as to [edit] into your post the exact steps you followed indicated by "it" we could determine which of the answers in the called duplicate you attempted and why that didn't work for you. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek nevermind it works now I restarded and the main gpu is the discreet

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted.